# State is not updated in StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

After some trial I discovered following problem occurs in strict mode.
I would be interested if someone can explain why.

Take this simple example where inside render **I am just scheduling a timeout which updates state**:

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cvgkjn?file=src%2FApp.js):

```
let firstRender = true; // Normally I would use ref but I was playing with example

export default function App() {
  let [data, setData] = React.useState({ name: 'Nick' });

  // Schedule a timeout on first render
  if (firstRender) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Running');

      setData((ps) => ({
        ...ps,
        name: 'Paul',
      }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  console.log('Running render');
  firstRender = false;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you run **this example without Strict mode**, then you will see "Paul" on screen after one second, as I was expecting.

If you use Strict mode, it will always show "Nick" on screen. Idea why?

<sub>**Note**: it seems using `useRef` instead of the global variable `firstRender` fixes this problem also in Strict mode. This seems to happen because `ref` was set in first render, and its value also got discarded (see also the answer).</sub>

Comment: Just to be clear, the word "text", is turning to the word "Nick" after 1 sec?

Comment: @RaoVirinchi I simplified example. Yeah note the differences in rendered result between using strict mode and not using it

Comment: Don't use normal variable use a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: @ShivamJha Even if that fixes I would be interested why such behavior happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the fact that strict mode [intentionally invokes your function component body twice](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) (when in dev mode) to help spot unintended side effects.

On the second invocation, your `firstRender` variable is `false` so your setTimeout doesn't run.

Important to note that this second invocation ***isn't just a re-render like you'd get from a state update***. It's a second invocation of the entire component body. State is not preserved. React invokes your component function once, discards the result, and invokes it a second time to get the output.

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

> Because the above methods might be called more than once, it’s important that they do not contain side-effects.

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:

> - Function component bodies

Comment: check the logs you will see it runs in both modes

Comment: It logs "Running Render" twice, but "Running" only once.

Comment: @rayhatfield even entering `setTimeout` once should be enough to see updated state (`'Paul'`) isn't it?

Comment: It "double invokes Function component bodies". On the second invocation you've already set `firstRender` to false and the state is reset.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify that this isn't a re-render, it's a second invocation of the entire component body. So the state isn't preserved between invocations here.

Comment: Now this makes more sense but why it works with `useref` then if state is not preserved? Do you have more info how second invocation is different from re render? Links?

Comment: It works with useRef because the ref is initialized _within the component_. If you run it again, you get a new ref with the initial value again. In the first example `firstRender` exists independently of the component and doesn't get re-initialized, so you get different behavior on a second invocation, which is the whole point of the double invocation--to expose this kind of subtle side effect.

Comment: If you have link explaining how second invocation is different from re render would be nice. Thanks

Comment: It's different from a re-render in that React is invoking your entire component body twice to get the initial output. It's not rendering it to the DOM and then updating. It's calling it once, discarding the result, and calling it a second time. I'm not aware of any resources I can point to that explains it further, but I haven't gone looking for any.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but I'm not seeing how I could correct it with the `useRef` hook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74463125/reducer-sets-wrong-state-when-reacts-strict-mode-is-enabled

Answer (score -1):

> Q. it seems using useRef instead of the global variable firstRender
> fixes this problem also in Strict mode. Curious why that's the case?

According to [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref),

Ref is also useful to keep some mutable value around. **The value stores in ref, will not change during subsequent re-renders, unless explicitly changed.**

Therefore, for values you don't want to change (maybe some expensive calculation) or for other reasons, use `useRef`.

> The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is
> mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a
> class.
>
> This works because useRef() creates a plain JavaScript object. The
> only difference between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object
> yourself is that useRef will give you the same ref object on every
> render.
>
> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes.
> **[Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)**. If you want
> to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node,
> you may want to use a callback ref instead.